# dual behaviour on passing referrer between http and https with 301 redirects

Tags: https, http, 301-redirect

We have a client that is using https but has two 301 redirects, first redirect from https to http, and second from http to https.

One of his referrers is sending from https referrer to https but the referrer parameter is not sent further to http.

Another referrer is sending from http referrer to https and curiously this referrer gets on to the first http 301 redirect and then further on to the second 301 https redirect.

I must mention that the referrers sites are NOT using any meta tags like .
Of course, our client does not have any access to any of the referrers sites.

The client needs the referrer parameter sent on through the redirects in all cases, but this does not happen.

I am completely overthrown by this behavior and would like to know if there are others that have encountered this kind of situation, and, if any, what solution/solutions might there be for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons referer is not passed in https=>http redirection expect if you use a special meta:

http://smerity.com/articles/2013/where_did_all_the_http_referrers_go.html

For security reasons you should use https everywhere, which will solve your problem too.